# Dativ oder Akkusativ?

Tags: dative, accusative

I've just checked the solutions of an exercise that asks me to determine the Kasus of two articles. Here it is:

> - Der Maler zeichnet ein Bild auf [...] Straße.
> - Die Kinder laufen so schnell wie möglich über [...] Platz.

To answer questions like these I usually ask myself: *"Wo oder wohin?"*, so I filled the gaps as it follows:

> - Der Maler zeichnet ein Bild auf **der** Straße.
> - Die Kinder laufen so schnell wie möglich über **dem** Platz.

and that is because the question that makes sense to me is "Wo?" in both cases, then I think I must use Dativ.

However the solutions provided by the book suggest to use the Akkusativ:

> - Der Maler zeichnet ein Bild auf **die** Straße.
> - Die Kinder laufen so schnell wie möglich über **die** Platz.

Can anyone tell me then where I'm wrong?

Thank you, really, in advance.

Comment: Your book is not good at all. _Platz_ is masculine so _über **die** Platz_ is not even possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To start with your first example, **both** of the following are correct; but they mean different things.

(i) Der Maler zeichnet ein Bild auf **der** Straße.
(ii) Der Maler zeichnet ein Bild auf **die** Straße.

The first sentence means that the painter was **in** the street when he drew the picture. The second means that he drew the picture **onto** the street. (So, he had some chalk and got down on his knees and drew something onto the asphalt).

Thus, ‘auf’ can take **Dat** *or* **Acc**, but the meaning changes. Roughly, the difference is this: with Dat, ‘auf’ answers the question *where?* and describes where something or someone is currently located. With Acc, ‘auf’ answers the question *into/onto where?*. If you look up [auf](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auf_Praeposition) in the Duden, you’ll find more details. Here’s another example that may help tease out the difference:

(iii) Er sitzt auf der Mauer. [He is sitting on the wall.]
(iv) Er klettert auf die Mauer. [He is climbing onto the wall.]

Turning to your second example, the situation is much the same: ‘über’ can take Dat or Acc, depending on what you want to express. (See [here](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueber_auf_darueber_darauf) for details.) In particular, ‘über **dem** Platz’ means ‘**above** the square’, whereas ‘über **den** Platz’ means ‘**across** the square. Thus, while your ‘Die Kinder laufen so schnell wie möglich über dem Platz.’ is grammatically possible, it makes less sense than ‘Die Kinder laufen so schnell wie möglich über den Platz.’ As was already pointed out in the comments, the answer the book suggests (‘Die Kinder laufen so schnell wie möglich über die Platz.’) is decidedly false!