# Dativ and akkusativ problem

Tags: dative, accusative

Can someone explain to me why these sentences are in accusative and not in dative case:

1- Alle drei schauen konzentriert auf den Verkehr

2- Die Sanitäter heben ihn auf eine Trage

And I can't understand the case in this sentence:

3- Der Krankenpfleger legt dem Opfer eine Atemmaske auf das Gesicht

Comment: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/2Kasus.html?lang=en

Comment: "Why" invites answers like "because that's how it is" - could you elaborate a bit? Simply [edit] your question, thanks!  And welcome to German Language SE. Don't forget to take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more.

Comment: Why would you expect these sentences to use dative case?

Comment: @Matthias I am a beginner in german but shouldn't "auf" be followed by dative ?

Comment: No, _auf_ is one of the many prepositions that are followed by either dative or accusative. You should find something like http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/index.html?MenuId=Word73 in every beginner's book on German Grammer.

Comment: If I may be so bold as to reference my own answer, we had another [Dat vs Acc question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38164/dativ-oder-akkusativ) today in connection with ‚auf‘. Perhaps that will help a little? The short answer is that in your examples, ‚auf‘ descries a destination *towards which* a movement is executed, not a location *in which* something is happening. (Cf. e.g. ‚Er liegt auf eine**r** Trage‘ – where ‚auf‘ is followed by Dat.)

Comment: @MarkOxford thanks your answer is very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Auf** does the job of the four English prepositions **on**, **to**, **onto** and **at**. Accusative means a direction while dative means being at a place.

> Alle drei schauen konzentriert auf de**n** Verkehr.

*All three watch (at) the traffic carefully.*

> Alle drei schauen konzentriert auf de**m** Verkehr.

*All three watch carefully while being on top of the traffic.* (Whatever that should mean…)

> Die Sanitäter heben ihn auf eine Trage.

*The paramedics lift him onto a barrow.*

> Die Sanitäter heben ihn auf eine**r** Trage.

*The paramedics lift him while being on top of a barrow.*

> Der Krankenpfleger legt dem Opfer eine Atemmaske auf das Gesicht. (Akkusativ)

*The caregiver puts a breathing mask at/onto the face of the victim.*

> "Der Krankenpfleger legt dem Opfer eine Atemmaske auf dem Gesicht." (Dativ, kein gültiger Satz)

*"The caregiver puts a breathing mask, while being on top of the face of the victim."* (not a valid sentence because the place where something is put at is missing.)

---

Your examples make little to no sense with dative. Here are some where accusative vs. dative really matters:

> Ich sehe einen Storch auf dem Nest flattern.

*I see a stork flapping on top of the nest.*

> Ich sehe einen Storch auf das Nest flattern.

*I see a stork flapping onto the nest.*

> Wir gehen auf dem Fest auf die Tanzfläche.

*At the fest, we go onto the dance floor.*

> Wir gehen auf das Fest auf der Tanzfläche.

*We go to the fest happening at the dance floor.*